# Get Transaction details using Python

Tags: transactions, tokens, web3.py

I'm trying to get details of a given transaction (Datetime, Sender, Receiver, Name of Token Transerref, quantity). [This is an example.](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x77e678921f642e327a7ad426bd7ee1db8011c31d1d61ec8991db0e87a7c4419a)
I don't know any API or method can allow me to get these data. I have looked into [Etherscan API](https://docs.etherscan.io/) but I didn't find any related endpoint Endpoint. Reading a previous question I found EtherChain APIs but they don't work anymore. Someone can help me? Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://www.chainstack.com) here!

You can use the Web3.py library to get the details of a given Ethereum transaction, including the timestamp, sender, receiver, name of the token transferred, and the quantity.

> Note that the transferred token and quantity depend on the specific transaction logic.

Below is an example that demonstrates how to achieve this for the [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x77e678921f642e327a7ad426bd7ee1db8011c31d1d61ec8991db0e87a7c4419a) you linked:

```py
from web3 import Web3
import datetime

# ERC-20 ABI for transfer event, name, and symbol
erc20_abi = [
    {
        "constant": True,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [{"name": "", "type": "string"}],
        "payable": False,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
    },
    {
        "constant": True,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "symbol",
        "outputs": [{"name": "", "type": "string"}],
        "payable": False,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
    },
    {
        "anonymous": False,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": True,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address",
            },
            {
                "indexed": True,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address",
            },
            {
                "indexed": False,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "value",
                "type": "uint256",
            },
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event",
    },
]


def get_transaction_details(w3, tx_hash):
    # Get transaction receipt to find block number
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
    if tx_receipt is None:
        print("Transaction receipt not found")
        return None

    # Get block details for timestamp
    block = w3.eth.get_block(tx_receipt["blockNumber"])
    if block is None:
        print("Block not found")
        return None
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        block["timestamp"], tz=datetime.timezone.utc
    )

    # Get transaction details for sender and receiver
    tx = w3.eth.get_transaction(tx_hash)
    sender = tx["from"]
    receiver = tx["to"]

    # Create contract object inside the function
    contract = w3.eth.contract(
        address="0x967da4048cD07aB37855c090aAF366e4ce1b9F48", abi=erc20_abi
    )

    # Decode logs
    logs = contract.events.Transfer().process_receipt(tx_receipt)
    if len(logs) == 0:
        print("No Transfer events found")
        return None

    # Find the Transfer event that matches both the sender and receiver
    matching_log = None
    for log in logs:
        if log["args"]["from"] == sender and log["args"]["to"] == receiver:
            matching_log = log
            break

    if matching_log is None:
        print("No matching Transfer event found")
        return None

    # Extract token name, symbol, and quantity
    token_name = contract.functions.name().call()
    token_symbol = contract.functions.symbol().call()
    quantity = matching_log["args"]["value"]

    return {
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "sender": sender,
        "receiver": receiver,
        "token_name": token_name,
        "token_symbol": token_symbol,
        "quantity": quantity,
    }


# Initialize Web3
w3 = Web3(
    Web3.HTTPProvider(
        "YOUR_ENDPOINT"
    )
)

# Transaction hash
tx_hash = "0x77e678921f642e327a7ad426bd7ee1db8011c31d1d61ec8991db0e87a7c4419a"

# Get transaction details
details = get_transaction_details(w3, tx_hash)
if details:
    print(f"Timestamp: {details['timestamp']}")
    print(f"Sender: {details['sender']}")
    print(f"Receiver: {details['receiver']}")
    print(f"Token Name: {details['token_name']}")
    print(f"Token Symbol: {details['token_symbol']}")
    print(f"Quantity: {details['quantity']}")
```

This code will give you all the details you need for a given transaction hash. Make sure to replace the contract address and the transaction hash with the ones you want.

> Also, add your endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much work and how many calls you expect to make, there are plenty of blockbook implemntations and derivatives deployed that would return what you want in json, with the caveat that you will likely be rate-limited if you make a ton of requests. The upside is that it's very popular as a wallet backend so you will have alternatives as long as you can find them.

Example of tx info returned from the official Trezor implementation: https://eth1.trezor.io/api/v2/tx/0xb031b7ee49faa4043c9a1c1ca3b2a803b5d1d4735a9bd3be0c6980035fde2f90

Documentation, including api endpoints: https://github.com/trezor/blockbook

Blockbook is also the backend for Trustwallet and Guarda and Infinity Wallet and Zelcore, amongst others. They all have some differences though, but documentation is generally available on github.